# Registering a custom mediatype in HATEOAS does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to register media type "application/vnd.contactdir.v1+json" but nothing happens and I keep receiving non-HAL json.

Here is my media type provider,

```
public class ContactDirMediaTypeConfigurationProvider implements MediaTypeConfigurationProvider {

  @Override
  public Class<? extends HypermediaMappingInformation> getConfiguration() {
    return ContactDirMediaTypeConfiguration.class;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supportsAny(Collection<MediaType> mediaTypes) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

media type config

```
@Configuration
public class ContactDirMediaTypeConfiguration implements HypermediaMappingInformation {

  @Override
  public List<MediaType> getMediaTypes() {
    return MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/vnd.contactdir.v1+json");
  }
}
```

and controller method

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/contacts",
      produces = {"application/vnd.contactdir.v1+json", "application/hal+json"})
  public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<ContactDto>> getAllContacts() {
    List<ContactDto> list = contactListService.getAllContacts();
    CollectionModel<ContactDto> collectionModel = linkAppender.appendLinks(list);
    collectionModel.add(
        linkTo(methodOn(ContactListController.class).getAllContacts()).withSelfRel());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(collectionModel, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

I noticed something strange when outputted [the list of message converters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjxeN.png): some of them repeated twice and one had my media type (with index 1). And If I set supportedMediaType to my type in all of them, json output of getAllContacts() will have correct HAL but I want custom type registration to work as it's described in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#mediatypes.custom). What am I missing?

**UPDATE 1**

After some more research I figured out that presence of my type in the first TypeConstrainedMapperJackson2HttpMessageConverter only gives a correct result but along with this I've completely got confused.

**UPDATE 2**

Now I tried to replace ObjectMapper from the first converter with ObjectMapper from the second one and the output became correct. Seems like the problem is in the mapper for converter which supports my media type. I modified its configuration type:

```
@Configuration
public class ContactDirMediaTypeConfiguration implements HypermediaMappingInformation {

  @Override
  public Module getJacksonModule() {
    return new Jackson2HalModule();
  }

  @Override
  public List<MediaType> getMediaTypes() {
    return MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/vnd.contactdir.v1+json, application/hal+json");
  }
}
```

but still nothing. Then I compared (manually, via debug as I could) working mapper with provided by the config above and found none differences. Worth to note that replacing the mappers works only if @EnableHyperMediaSupport added. In other case it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to make configuration in that way:

```
@Configuration
public class ContactDirMediaTypeConfiguration implements HypermediaMappingInformation {

  @Override
  public Module getJacksonModule() {
    return new Jackson2HalModule();
  }

  @Override
  public ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper(ObjectMapper mapper) {

    mapper.registerModule(getJacksonModule());
    mapper.setHandlerInstantiator(new Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(new EvoInflectorLinkRelationProvider(),
        CurieProvider.NONE, MessageResolver.DEFAULTS_ONLY));

    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

    return mapper;
  }

  @Override
  public List<MediaType> getMediaTypes() {
    return MediaType.parseMediaTypes("application/vnd.contactdir.v1+json");
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/1253#issuecomment-608973523